# Scripts inside ng-view not working (JQuery is loaded before angular) when referenced from a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angular-routing

I'm using angular and angular-route. The index.html looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="Showcase">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>UCSD Showcase</title>
    <base href="/showcase/">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="routes.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/initGlobalHelpers.js"></script>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="#########################################">
    <meta name="keywords" content="###############################################">
    <meta property="og:url" content="#">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="CSES OSS">
    <meta property="og:image" content="############################################################################################">
    <meta property="og:description" content="#">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <meta name="twitter:site_name" content="CSS OSS">
    <meta name="twitter:site" content="################">
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary">
    <meta name="twitter:description" content="#">
    <meta name="twitter:image" content="#">
    <meta name="image" content="#">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="./styles/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<ng-view></ng-view>
</body>
</html>
```

And then for my home page when I'm using

```html
<h1>This is the home page</h1>
<script src="home.html"></script>
```

I get the a warning

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.     jquery.min.js:4

and an error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token <   angular.js:13550

However when I replace that script that by the content of the script which basically ends up looking like:

```html
<h1>This is the home page</h1>
<script>
    console.log('Hi!');
</script>
```

Then it works.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Use ngInclude instead of html script tag

```
<div ng-include="'home.html'"></div>
```

See ngInclude docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)

Comment: I tried this. Didn't work. I'm still confused as to how this is supposed to load home.js because the docs say that it can be used to inject html (so how can we load javascript?)